# How to Access, Control Datagridview of external winform app?

Tags: datagridview, winforms-interop

I have a .net winform app with 1 form and 1 dgv control.

Can someone kindly suggest or share some starting points so that i can move ahead? Im badly stuck with this requirement for days....

What i need is a way to access that datagridview and manipulate the data from another winform app in few ways like:

1. copy/paste single or multiple rows
2. edit data/rows
3. right click on a row

I searched and found some ways like windows api and ui automation stuff but i could not find more details or any example to perform above actions especially with datagridview control.

Can someone kindly suggest or share some starting points so that i can move ahead? Im badly stuck with this requirement for days....

Thanks....

I searched and found some ways like windows api and ui automation stuff but i could not find more details to perform above actions especially with datagridview control example.

[Here is the attached image of my problem...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJU2t.png)

Comment: You can use **Inspect** tool from MS SDK to get the UIAutomation hierarchy/properties of the DGV and do some tests like changing values, then you can write the code from the hierarchy/properties 
 Another way is by DLL injection. I just tested with a CLR DLL and I could get the IWin32Window of the DGV to access it, but it is more complicated...
 UIAutomation is the simplest method.

Comment: Hi  Castorix,I agree UIA is better than windows api but still not easy to use in case of automating dgv control...Im still stuck on this issue & exploring other testing frameworks

Comment: I just did some tests in C# with UIA and a DGV from a VB program
It works fine; the only problem is that the lines are localized (french for me : "Ligne du haut" for header, then "Ligne 0", "Ligne 1", etc...) 
You can test **Inspect** on a DGV to check if they are localized in your language
 
But I could identify them by their ControlTypeIds (_UIA_ControlTypeIds.UIA_CustomControlTypeId_)
and I could get and set values in the DGV by using **IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern**

Screen copy of Inspect with localized DGV lines =>[DGV Inspect](https://i.ibb.co/Y3DFwwz/DGV-Inspect.jpg)

Comment: thanks Castorix, I will explore more on UIA!!